Zero-inflated negbin regression warnings after permutation of data
I am applying a zeroinfl negbin regression to my data. Specifically, my dependent variable is a count variable (centrality measure), while my independent/controls are both binary and continous.
I've run the regression on my data in R, but now to calculate the p-values (as the Y is a centrality measure) I am randomizing Y 10,000 times, and recalculating 10,000 zeroinfl negbin to produce the distribution of the coefficients. However,at the end of the process, some warnings pop up, including:

glm.fit: numerically estimated rates equal to 0 have occurred
glm.fit: the algorithm does not converge
In pnbinom(0, mu = mu, size = theta, log.p = TRUE) :
bgrat(a=21, b=2.04429e-11, x=1, y=1.1354e-315): z=2.32756e-314, b*z == 0 underflow, hence inaccurate pbeta()
In pnbinom(0, mu = mu, size = theta, log.p = TRUE) :
pnbinom_mu() -> bratio() gave error code 11.

My dataset is composed of 177 observations.
This is the code I am using:
library(pscl)

dput(variables_meetQ1)
structure(list(name = c("N0003", "N0005", "N0007", "N0010", "N0011", 
"N0013", "N0014", "N0015", "N0020", "N0021", "N0024", "N0025", 
"N0033", "N0034", "N0035", "N0039", "N0041", "N0042", "N0043", 
"N0044", "N0045", "N0046", "N0047", "N0048", "N0051", "N0053", 
"N0055", "N0057", "N0058", "N0060", "N0063", "N0064", "N0067", 
"N0069", "N0071", "N0074", "N0075", "N0077", "N0078", "N0079", 
"N0080", "N0082", "N0083", "N0089", "N0095", "N0096", "N0102", 
"N0107", "N0109", "N0110", "N0113", "N0114", "N0115", "N0116", 
"N0119", "N0121", "N0123", "N0125", "N0127", "N0128", "N0133", 
"N0135", "N0136", "N0139", "N0143", "N0146", "N0156", "N0157", 
"N0158", "N0160", "N0161", "N0162", "N0163", "N0177", "N0183", 
"N0186", "N0187", "N0204", "N0230", "N0251", "N0259", "N0263", 
"N0264", "N0284", "N0287", "N0300", "N0327", "N0341", "N0346", 
"N0373", "N0393", "N0399", "N0431", "N0439", "N0441", "N0443", 
"N0447", "N0451", "N0469", "N0480", "N0481", "N0504", "N0537", 
"N0542", "N0552", "N0553", "N0570", "N0571", "N0572", "N0581", 
"N0582", "N0583", "N0609", "N0610", "N0626", "N0629", "N0646", 
"N0663", "N0664", "N0675", "N0767", "N0782", "N0783", "N0792", 
"N0801", "N0811", "N0829", "N0831", "N0833", "N0856", "N0879", 
"N0890", "N0893", "N0900", "N0905", "N0934", "N0939", "N0947", 
"N0955", "N1112", "N1119", "N1123", "N1149", "N1181", "N1190", 
"N1196", "N1366", "N1367", "N0832", "N1325", "N0874", "N1145", 
"N0466", "N0239", "N0768", "N0052", "N0409", "N0619", "N0679", 
"N0295", "N0478", "N0023", "N0076", "N0200", "N0475", "N0242", 
"N0203", "N0270", "N0292", "N1182", "N0054", "N0659", "N0026", 
"N0132", "N0134", "N0322", "N0470"), Leader = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Age_centred = c(-22.39415205, 7.605847953, 12.60584795, 
9.605847953, -3.394152047, -0.394152047, 12.60584795, 1.605847953, 
0.605847953, -25.39415205, -22.39415205, 12.60584795, 7.605847953, 
19.60584795, 14.60584795, -16.39415205, -7.394152047, 36.60584795, 
-21.39415205, 14.60584795, -10.39415205, 25.60584795, 2.605847953, 
22.60584795, 6.605847953, 9.605847953, -11.39415205, -3.394152047, 
2.605847953, -24.39415205, 26.60584795, 1.605847953, 3.605847953, 
-2.394152047, -0.394152047, 24.60584795, -0.394152047, 0.605847953, 
30.60584795, -3.394152047, 25.60584795, 0.605847953, 3.605847953, 
0.605847953, 15.60584795, 4.605847953, 21.60584795, -10.39415205, 
25.60584795, 10.60584795, 31.60584795, -8.394152047, -10.39415205, 
-5.394152047, -2.394152047, -16.39415205, -4.394152047, -7.394152047, 
40.60584795, -11.39415205, -8.394152047, 33.60584795, 25.60584795, 
6.605847953, -5.394152047, 11.60584795, -26.39415205, -2.394152047, 
1.605847953, 12.60584795, 2.605847953, -30.39415205, -25.39415205, 
-14.39415205, -1.394152047, 11.60584795, 8.605847953, 11.60584795, 
-8.394152047, -25.39415205, 3.605847953, -15.39415205, -18.39415205, 
-3.394152047, 36.60584795, -6.394152047, 29.60584795, -11.39415205, 
-0.394152047, -10.39415205, -26.39415205, -22.39415205, -8.394152047, 
-14.39415205, -26.39415205, -26.39415205, -26.39415205, -31.39415205, 
-19.39415205, -14.39415205, 10.60584795, -20.39415205, -3.394152047, 
12.60584795, 16.60584795, -0.394152047, 6.605847953, -6.394152047, 
-12.39415205, 7.605847953, -5.394152047, -14.39415205, 13.60584795, 
-26.39415205, -3.394152047, -9.394152047, 12.60584795, -15.39415205, 
-13.39415205, -24.39415205, 0.605847953, -15.39415205, -3.394152047, 
-18.39415205, -1.394152047, 17.60584795, -12.39415205, -14.39415205, 
-20.39415205, -5.394152047, 3.605847953, -20.39415205, -17.39415205, 
0.605847953, -19.39415205, -9.394152047, -27.39415205, -27.39415205, 
-16.39415205, 19.60584795, 24.60584795, 5.605847953, -3.394152047, 
-11.39415205, 7.605847953, 11.60584795, -13.39415205, -13.39415205, 
-16.39415205, -23.39415205, -5.394152047, 4.605847953, -23.39415205, 
-4.394152047, -5.394152047, -0.394152047, 21.60584795, -22.39415205, 
-0.394152047, -5.394152047, 0.605847953, -0.394152047, -5.394152047, 
30.60584795, -10.39415205, 1.605847953, -9.394152047, 25.60584795, 
-0.394152047, -28.39415205, -1.394152047, 28.60584795, -25.39415205, 
-4.394152047, -6.394152047, -9.394152047, -16.39415205), n_kinship = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 9, 10, 7, 11, 1, 0, 3, 4, 1, 1, 0, 0, 8, 4, 0, 5, 3, 
2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 
3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 11, 7, 7, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
9, 1, 4, 2, 0, 4, 3, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
3, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 7, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 
6, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0), n_call = c(0, 0, 0, 9, 15, 7, 
0, 38, 9, 0, 3, 2, 6, 15, 13, 0, 29, 2, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 
5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 23, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 6, 63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 23, 29, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 3, 9, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 9, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 8, 3, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0), n_met5 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), liaison = c(0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 94, 1232, 0, 0, 0, 160, 0, 154, 
0, 0, 26, 0, 0, 694, 34, 0, 0, 320, 170, 62, 0, 0, 0, 10, 30, 
0, 0, 104, 0, 0, 0, 0, 354, 1658, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 72, 
0, 1404, 104, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 164, 0, 0, 0, 
72, 578, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 92, 0, 0, 4, 4, 50, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 177L), class = "data.frame")

zinb_M4 <- zeroinfl(liaison ~ Leader + Age_centred + n_kinship + n_call
                    |n_met5, data = variables_meetQ1,
                    na.action = na.omit ,dist="negbin")

permutation_matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = length(variables_meetQ1$liaison),ncol = 10000)

for (i in 1:10000)  {
  permutation_matrix[,i] <- sample(variables_meetQ1$liaison, 
                                   size=length(variables_meetQ1$liaison),replace = FALSE)
}

zinb_M4_perm <- list()

for (i in 1:10000){
zinb_M4_perm[[i]] <- zeroinfl(permutation_matrix[,i] ~ Leader + Age_centred + 
                                  n_kinship + n_call | n_met5, data = variables_meetQ1,
                                na.action = na.omit ,dist="negbin")
  
}


coef_M4 <-matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 10000)
for (i in 1:10000) {
  coef_M4[,i] <- as.matrix(unname(zinb_M4_perm[[i]]$coefficients$count)) 
}


Welcome to SO! To help others to help you, you should provide a reproducible example providing your datasets variables_meetQ1 so others can reproduce your problem. Read this for more infomration on how to prepare a REPREX. Also, you should provide the packaes loaded at the beginning of your code, I imagine you are using {pscl}, so add library(pscl) and other packages you used in your example. If you use the {reprex} package this is validated automatically.

Dear Josep, thank you very much for the suggestions! I have updated my post accordingly.

You're probably getting bootstrap replicates where the zero-inflation component is estimated as p=0 (or even more extremely, bootstrap reps with complete separation). Will dig in if I get a chance.

I don't actually think these warnings represent a serious problem - they will arise from permutation samples that are poorly posed in some way (like having complete separation, i.e. all of the zeros in a single data partition, or having the zero-inflation probability estimate go to zero [-Inf on the log-odds scale]). However, it's a good idea to figure out exactly what's going on.
Don't have time to dig all the way into this, but here is the beginning of a strategy for debugging.
This is a slightly condensed version of your code that sets a known seed at each iteration and stops whenever a warning occurs, so that you can then look at that particular set of permutation data (it might have been better to store all of the permutations, as in your code, and look at them afterwards, but it's slightly easier to just stop and see what's happening than to flag which iterations give rise to warnings ...
nperm <- 1e4
coef_M4 <-matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = nperm)
options(warn=3) ## warnings to errors
for (i in seq(nperm)) {
    cat(i, "\n")
    set.seed(1 + i)
    permsamp <- sample(variables_meetQ1$liaison, 
                       size=nrow(variables_meetQ1),
                       replace = FALSE)
    pfit <- zeroinfl(permsamp ~ Leader + Age_centred + n_kinship + n_call |n_met5,
             data = variables_meetQ1,
             na.action = na.omit ,dist="negbin")
    coef_M4[,i] <- as.matrix(unname(pfit$coefficients$count))
}

